# unable to Update JSON value in forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I've a json array where I want to update value of a key to some dummy. Here is my code.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}]


var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).forEach(item => item.name = 'Hi');

console.log(temp);
```

I get the output as `undefined`  but I want all the `name` values to be `Hi`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: use `.map` instead of `.forEach`, also don't stringify it first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why you Stringify it. It works without.

And use .map()

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}]


var temp = data.map(obj => {
   obj.name = "hi";
   return obj;
});

console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 6):

`Array.forEach` does return `undefined` so you won't get the array.

In your case, use `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}, {
  "name": "Abc1"
}]


var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).map(item => ({ ...item, name: 'Hi' }));

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: You can even get rid of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`, since `map` returns a new array

Comment: Total nitpick here, but `forEach` returns `undefined`.